# dropdown list fill from MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

i used these syntax to fill two dropdwon list, the second dropdownlist must be filled after i chose the fist one but the second one is embty, in mysql tables i have two tables to fill the dropdownlist, the first table contain the (gov_name) and (gove_id) and the second one contain (area_name) and (gov_id).

```
{
    DataSet ds_1;
    ListItem item_1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            fill_gov();
        }
    }

    private void fill_gov()
    {
        //Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";
        Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        connection = new SqlConnection((string)Session["conection"]);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select gov_name from gov";
        da_1.SelectCommand = command;
        ds_1 = new DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(ds_1, "gov");
        Session["Hospital"] = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        item_1 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Value = "0";
        item_1.Text = "select governement";
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(item_1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds_1.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            item_1 = new ListItem();
            item_1.Value = (ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gov_name"].ToString());
            item_1.Text = ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gov_name"].ToString();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(item_1);
        }

    }

    private void fill_area()
    {
       // Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";
        Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        connection = new SqlConnection((string)Session["conection"]);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select area_name from area where area_name !='' and cast (gov_id as varchar) ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";
        da_1.SelectCommand = command;
        ds_1 = new DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(ds_1, "area");
        Session["Hospital"] = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;
        DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
        item_1 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Value = "0";
        item_1.Text = "select area";
        DropDownList2.Items.Add(item_1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds_1.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            item_1 = new ListItem();
            item_1.Value = (ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["area_name"].ToString());
            item_1.Text = ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["area_name"].ToString();
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(item_1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please update the question the problem you are facing.

Comment: the problem is the second dropdownlist (area) is embty

Comment: You might be calling `fill_area()` in selected_index changed event.Check if `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` has value before calling the method.

Comment: are you using sql or mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in  `fill_gov()` you need to select both `gov_id` and `area_name`

```
 command.CommandText = "select gov_id, gov_name from gov";
```

set value from `gov_id`

```
item_1.Value = (ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gov_id"].ToString());
item_1.Text = ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gov_name"].ToString();
```

and change the `fill_area()` select sql as below

```
command.CommandText = "select area_name from area where area_name !='' and gov_id =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue ;
```

[you better use parameterized SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: i try it but still embty

Comment: what is the column type of `gov_id`?

Comment: @RamyNabilAkl then you don't need `''` for parameter

Comment: it gives me this error (Error converting data type varchar to float.) and when i remove '' its gives me this error Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.